# Nested If And Formula in Excel

Tags: excel, nested, formula

I have an excel document with various dates in Column A ranging from April, 2014 through April 2017.

I need to assign a number based on the month and year - April 2014 is 23 and it drops by 1 every month going forward.  So May 2014 is 22, June 2014 is 21 and so forth.  Once I get to March 2016, or 0, all dates greater than that are also 0.  My issue is that excel is treating April 2014 and April 2015 the same - they are both returning a value of 23.

Here is my code:

```
=IF(AND(MONTH(A2)=4,YEAR(A2=2014)),"23",IF(AND(MONTH(A2)=5,YEAR(A2=2014)),"22",IF(AND(MONTH(A2)=6,YEAR(A2=2014)),"21",IF(AND(MONTH(A2)=7,YEAR(A2=2014)),"20",IF(AND(MONTH(A2)=8,YEAR(A2=2014)),"19",IF(AND(MONTH(A2)=9,YEAR(A2=2014)),"18",IF(AND(MONTH(A2)=10,YEAR(A2=2014)),"17",IF(AND(MONTH(A2)=11,YEAR(A2=2014)),"16",IF(AND(MONTH(A2)=12,YEAR(A2=2014)),"15",IF(AND(MONTH(A2)=1,YEAR(A2=2015)),"14",IF(AND(MONTH(A2)=2,YEAR(A2=2015)),"13",IF(AND(MONTH(A2)=3,YEAR(A2=2015)),"12",IF(AND(MONTH(A2)=4,YEAR(A2=2015)),"11",IF(AND(MONTH(A2)=5,YEAR(A2=2015)),"10",IF(AND(MONTH(A2)=6,YEAR(A2=2015)),"9",IF(AND(MONTH(A2)=7,YEAR(A2=2015)),"8",IF(AND(MONTH(A2)=8,YEAR(A2=2015)),"7",IF(AND(MONTH(A2)=9,YEAR(A2=2015)),"6",IF(AND(MONTH(A2)=10,YEAR(A2=2015)),"5",IF(AND(MONTH(A2)=11,YEAR(A2=2015)),"4",IF(AND(MONTH(A2)=12,YEAR(A2=2015)),"3",IF(AND(MONTH(A2)=1,YEAR(A2=2016)),"2",IF(AND(MONTH(A2)=2,YEAR(A2=2016)),"1",IF(AND(MONTH(A2)=3,YEAR(A2=2016)),"0",IF(AND(MONTH(A2)>3,YEAR(A2=2016)),"0","0")))))))))))))))))))))))))
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use yearfrac instead.

```
    =IF(A2>DATE(2016,3,1),0,ROUND(YEARFRAC(DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2),1),DATE(2016,3,1))*12,0))
```

Yearfrac between your date (A2) and date(2016,3,1) will give you the portion of a year between the two which you can multiply by 12 and round to get the month number.  The if statement takes care of months after March.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=IF(A2<Date(2016,3,1),DATEDIF(A2,DATE(2016,3,1),"m"),0)
```